# Best available guide to Sencha?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

i'm very new to sencha and i need help with it.

can anyone give me few links regarding sencha tutorials and books....

on the other day i found out a site showing info and source code about sencha.

i remember it as sencha kitchen sink.....but now when i google it i couldn't find it if you know about this please help me with a link.......

thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is everything I have found useful over the last few weeks whilst I have been learning Sencha Touch, hope they help:

1) A number of videos can be found here: http://vimeo.com/15888504 (Andrew Neil's are particularly good, there are a few on layouts and one that takes you through how to create the GeoTweets sample app)

2) Sencha Docs - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/

3) Getting started doc (mentioned by Sachin above)

4) The examples included when you download Sencha (Kitchen sink etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Andrew Neil's videos.  They're the best way to get a quick overview that I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Sencha touch, then here is a very good tutorial to begin with.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html

Comment: Thank you @Sachin Shanbhag for your concern , do you any idea about kitchen sink............if you do please post me...........thank you.

Answer (score 1):

there is a good sencha touch book. Althoug it is not finished yet, but u can order this book.
check this url : http://manning.com/garcia2/

Answer (score 1):

Even everything you need can be found in links given above sometimes i take a look around these demos and their source to find solutions:

http://www.superatic.com/pr0v3/sencha-touch-beta-0.90/examples/

http://www.simoens.org/Sencha-Projects/demos/

Answer (score 1):

check latest docs on http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/

They have improved a lot in latest documentation and now there are a lot of examples also available to download unlike earlier when they had only couple of basic examples.

I think this would be the best documentation available. There are books but usually by the time they get to market, they are already outdated. So this would be the best resource for now.

Answer (score 0):

@Prateek Here's a 7-minute introductory video of Sencha Touch using the Kitchen Sink: http://vimeo.com/12636777

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This you can find docs about sencha

http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch

Answer (score 0):

Check out: this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849515107) at Amazon. I am almost done reading this, its pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Since docs and tutorials have already been mentioned try these books

1 - Sencha Touch Mobile JavaScript Framework

2 - Sencha Touch Cookbook

Also try some sample apps at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/index.html